# How to prove $f(x)=x\cos(x)$ is a many to one function?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, products, monotone-functions

I used Desmos to determine the graph of the function $f(x)=x\cos(x)$. Clearly, any horizontal line which is parallel to the $x$-axis cuts the graph at more than one point indicating the function is many-one.
I wish to prove it is many-one by using calculus, for which I differentiated $f(x)$ to get $f'(x)= \cos(x) - x\sin(x)$. Now we need to prove that the function is not monotonic by showing the derivative changes sign. But how to show that it's not monotonic?

Comment: How about just noting that $f(0) = f(\pi/2) = 0$?

Comment: Compute $f^{\prime \prime} (x)$.

Comment: Observe that $f(\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2})=0$ for all $n \in \Bbb{N}$.

Comment: If you are asking for calculus way , either you can graph $f'(x)$ or just find points that just give opposite signs for example $f(0)>0$ where as $f(\frac{\pi}{2})<0$

Comment: @littleO and Anurag A Please read the question more carefully.

Comment: @amsmath But also read the title. It is error on part of OP that the title says one thing and the questions asks something different.

Comment: @AnuragA Fair enough. ;-)

Comment: Why would you want to show the derivative is not monotonic?  It’s easy for a function to be one-to-one and yet have a non-monotonic derivative.  Seems like two separate questions.

Comment: For showing that a function isn't one-one, you need to show that it's derivative changes sign. Don't need monotonicity here

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Actually, when a functions derivative changes sign, its actually not monotonic since the meaning of monotonicity is its derivative must maintain the same sign to be either increasing or decreasing. I feel its not wrong to mention it in that way. Feel free to correct any mistake in my statement.

Comment: @ErickWong Kindly give me an example of a function which is one-to-one and having non-monotonic derivative. It would be helpful for me. Seems, I am unaware of such functions.

Comment: What I'm saying is that for showing that a differentiable function is many-one, you need to show that its derivative changes sign. There are examples of one-one functions with non-monotonic derivatives, e.g. $y=x^3$.

Comment: @GuruVishnu I suspect that you are conflating non-monotonicity of the function with non-monotonicity of its derivative.  Shunham’s example works fine, and so does $2x + \sin x$, whose derivative $2 + \cos x$ is highly non-monotonic.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri and Eric Wong Thank you for your comments. I now realised my mistake. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As for using a derivative of $f'(x) = \cos(x) - x\sin(x)$, note $f'\left(\left(2k + \frac{1}{2}\right)\pi\right) = -\left(2k + \frac{1}{2}\right)\pi$ and $f'\left(\left(2k - \frac{1}{2}\right)\pi\right) = \left(2k - \frac{1}{2}\right)\pi$ for all integers $k$. This shows that, for every $2\pi$ range, it goes from a continually larger negative to a larger positive value and then back to an even more negative value. Thus, it's not monotonic, as well as being unbounded.

For another, more direct way, note $f(2k\pi) = 2k\pi$ and $f((2k+1)\pi) = -(2k+1)\pi$ for all integers $k$. Next, since $f(x)$ is a continuous function, you can use this and the [Intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) to show that $f(x)$ is a many-to-one function for all real values.

Comment: Perfect answer!

Comment: @amsmath Thanks for the compliment. As the OP asked in the question text to show the derivative is not monotonic, I updated the answer to show this, including that it's periodic between being very negative & very positive with no lower or upper bound.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thank you very much for clarifying my doubt.

Comment: @GuruVishnu You're welcome. I'm glad I was able to give some help for you to understand things a bit better.